# Android Internal Storage partition

Tags: android, memory, storage, device, partition

How i can get access to internal storage partition which is available for users? On my HTC path is `/storage/emmc` in `Xperia /mnt/ext_card`. Is any function for get internat partition jut like for external storage `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()`

Comment: duplicate of [Best way to know sd card Path Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248510/best-way-to-know-sd-card-path-android) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546718/android-getting-internal-storage-absolute-path/17546843#17546843 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097466/access-files-on-internal-and-external-storage/13098219#13098219 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212377/external-internal-storage/11212430#11212430 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741939/android-find-all-internal-and-external-storage/9743324#9743324 and others

Comment: Environment.getDataDirectory() will give you path of internal memory.

Answer (score 0):

> To find locations on internal storage for your app, use `getFilesDir()`, called on any Context (such as your Activity, to get a File object).

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17546843/1182971) answer